# Weird format Date to `toLocaleString` in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I have an app that is currently running in Production. Suddenly, I have experienced a weird issue that I am not able to figure it out to prevent it. Any suggestion is highly appreciate.

This is the function where the error happened:

```
date_time: new Date(
                this.selectedDate.getFullYear(),
                this.selectedDate.getMonth(),
                this.selectedDate.getDate(),
                this.selectedHour.value.split(':')[0],
                this.selectedHour.value.split(':')[1],
                0
              ).toLocaleString(),
```

This `date_time` will be saved in database.
Output Example: `12/9/2021, 2:00:00 PM`. Everything is working as expected.
However, today there is new record in database with different format: `12/9/2021 2:00:00 p.m.` And it messed up my app. Do you know what happen to `toLocaleString()`  ? Thank you.

Comment: If you require a specific format (i.e. for software-to-software communication), use that specific format instead of using the user's locale.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for your response. The funny thing is that, the app have been running for almost 6 months without any issue. Just out of the blue, I got this issue.

Comment: store as datetime, not that format

Comment: It can be different each and every time. The fact that the locale was always the same before means nothing

Comment: The result of [*toLocaleString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) with no options is implementation dependent (and not necessarily reliable otherwise). That you've not had any issues in 6 months is pure chance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) I assume this code is running client-side and sending the resulting string to the server for insertion into your database.

`toLocaleString` converts a date to a string formatted **for the user's locale**.

It is designed to display a **human readable** date.

If a user with their system set to a different locale (likely because they are from a different country to you) then it will give different results.

If you want a *standard* date in a format that is easily machine processable (i.e. good for storing in a database) then use [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

You can parse it and convert it to a local string for display later.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are correct. The funny thing is that, the app have been running for almost 6 months without any issue. Just out of the blue, I got this issue.

Comment: So I am just gonna store something like : `new Date()` in the database then use toISOString to read it. Instead of storing `toLocaleString`.

Comment: `new Date()` creates a date object. `toISOString()` converts that date object into a good format for storing in a database.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.